# how to dynamically annotate x axis based on file name

Tags: r, plot, axis, highlight

I have a read a series of 2D data frame files into my R environment and want to plot their content.

An example file name is:

> MEF_85686672-85692745_orientation_+_overlap_2073_regulation_.txt

```
head(MEF_85686672-85692745_orientation_+_overlap_2073_regulation_.txt)
    1     85686673          97.51475
    2     85686674          98.51475
    3     85686675          100.51475
    4     85686676          44.51542
    5     85686677          97.50000
```

to be able to iterate through these files I make a list of these files:

```
MEF=ls()[grep(ls(), pattern='MEF')]
```

Then I plot the files' contents one after the other

```
    plot_files=function(MEF){
      mef=get(MEF[i])
      tryCatch(
      plot(mef[,1], (mef[,2]/mean(mef[1:1000,2])), 
      main = gsub('.txt','',gsub('MEF_nuc_occupancy_region','',paste(MEF[i]))), xlab="bp", 
      ylab="Occupancy", type='l', ylim=c(min(mi),max(ma)), col='red'),
      error=function() next);
```

All of the above is fine it is when I try to finish the function to further annotate the plots based on the file-variable's name, problems occur. I want to highlight the x-axis based on the presence or absence of a '+' sign between the regular patterns 'orientation' and 'overlap' in the file names.

```
if(substr(paste(MEF[i]), regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_orientation_')+13, regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_overlap_')-1)=='+'){
   rect(xleft=85692000, xright=nrow(mef), ybottom=par("usr")[3], ytop=par("usr")[4], density=NA, col="lightgray")
   }
}
```

if a '+' sign is present. The number in the filename that occurs between 'overlap' and 'regulation' will be taken and from this number (subtracted from the  to the number of rows) to the end of the x axis.

and so when I use this plot function and iterate through each to the files:

```
for(i in seq(length(MEF))){
  tryCatch(plot_files(MEF,ESC), error=function(e) e)
}
```

The first problem is that nothing is highlighted in any of the plots... I first suspected that this may be due to the overlaps on the regions being to small to be visible in the context of the whole x axis. However some of the overlaps are quite large and yet none of the resulting plots' x-axes are highlighted:

[image]

So when I try to debug it with an artificial number (85692000) and try to extend the highlighting to the right end of the axis, as such:

```
if(substr(paste(MEF[i]), regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_orientation_')+13, regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_overlap_')-1)=='+'){
rect(xleft=85692000, xright=nrow(mef), ybottom=par("usr")[3], ytop=par("usr")[4], density=NA, col="lightgray")
}
```

The following plot results:
[image]

So not only is the highlight extending from the wrong end of the x-axis but it is also not covering the entire plot- i just want to highlight the x-axis with a line... (NOTE: I will sort out the colour and density later)

All I want is a plot the highlights the x-axis as follows:

[image]

One that highlights the x axis from the end of the axis to the number corresponding to overlap in the variable name, subtracted from the length of the x- axis (NOTE: I will work on the alternative case where there is a '-' rather than '+', later- in which case the highlight will extend from the left of the axis rather than the right)

Comment: Don't use `assign`. Use lists and `lapply()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
for(i in seq(length(MEF))){
  x1=get(MEF[i])
  x2=get(ESC[i])
  #png(filename=paste('PNG/', MEF[i], '.png', sep=''));
  p=ggplot(data=x1, aes(V1,V2))
  xmin=x1[1,1]+(nrow(x1)-as.numeric(substr(paste(MEF[i]), regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_overlap_')+9, regexpr(paste(MEF[i]), pattern='_regulation_')-1)))
  xmax=x1[nrow(x1),1]
  p=p+geom_line(aes(colour='black'))+geom_line(data=x2, aes(V1,V2, colour='red'))+scale_colour_manual(labels = c("MEF", "ESC"),values = c("black","red"))+theme_bw()+labs(x='bp', y='Occupancy')+geom_rect(aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=-10, ymax=0), color="blue",fill='blue', alpha=0.01, inherit.aes = FALSE)
  print(p)
  #dev.off();
}
```

[image]